# A bijective monotone function is continuous. Is my Proof correct?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to improve my proof writing due to exams. Is this proof even correct in the first place and understandable? if not what could be improved?

> Proof that a bijective monotone function is continous

Assume this were not the case. Assume wlog that $f$ is increasing. Then there would be a sequence $x_n$ such that $\lim f(x_n)\neq f(x)$, where $x$ is the limit. Choose $f(y_n)=f(x)-1/n$ and $f(y'_n)=f(x)+1/n$. We can do this, because $f$ is surjective. We note that $f(y_n)\leq f(x)-1/n\leq f(x) \leq f(x)+1/n\leq f(y_n')$. Because $f$ is monotone we find $y_n \leq x \leq y_n'$. This implies that for some $N$ with $n \geq N$ we have $y_n\leq x_n\leq y_n'$. But then again due to the fact that $f$ is monotone we find $f(y_n)\leq f(x_n) \leq f(y_n')$. If we take the limit and due to a corollary of the Squeeze theorem we find that $f(x)\leq \lim f(x_n) \leq f(x)$. But then $\lim f(x_n)=f(x)$. A contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should give us the problem more precisely. What kind of function is this? I.e. what are domain and codomain? The problem doesn't make any sense without this information. Your reasoning is mostly fine, though there is a slight gap in your proof.

You have to argue more carefully that $y_n \leq x_n \leq y_n'$ for $n \gg 0$. This does not follow from $y_n \leq x \leq y_n'$. However, if you're slightly more accurate in your argument, then this step can be fixed.

The rest of the proof is correct, but it is redundant (and unpleasant) to phrase this as a proof by contradiction. That was not needed and this proof is really a direct proof if you look at it again. You should also write "Choose a sequence $(y_n)_n$ such that $f(y_n) = \dots$" instead of what you did.

Comment: This feedback overlaps with the feedback my tutor always gives me. I have to introduce and describe things very precicse. I knew that the gap was there but I think I have to be more accurate. I didnt even notice that the proof by contradiction wasn't necessary. I always try to convert  for all into existence statements because it is easier to handle the single case. But my research inducates that I shouldn't use contradiction and alwys try to do a direct proof. So should I avoid proof by contradiction?

Comment: @Iwan5050 It's not that you should avoid proofs by contradiction, only that your proof is a direct proof that you phrased as a proof by contradiction which is rather misleading because in no way you actually used anything about indirect proofs. I guess my advice for you is to always look back at your proof and scrutinize what you actually do and which steps are actually needed.

Comment: ok thank you for you're effort and time